# Can't find element ID in google maps for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-maps, selenium-webdriver, xpath

So I am trying to automate favoriting a large list of companies on Google Maps (about 500 or so) and it starts to work until a company doesn't have a website then the location of the Save button moves and the `xpath` in selenium clicks on "Send to your Phone" which breaks the script. I have tried finding the element ID for the Save button but I can't find it anywhere. Any ideas on what to do to get around this? [Here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Day+Star+Mechanical/@54.2131969,-123.9513457,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x53715f5ea3f859bb:0x2c5dd94ac84c9db1!8m2!3d54.5455828!4d-115.0001885) is the link for the second setup that breaks the script and [here](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Comfort-Aire+Limited/@52.3156728,-113.8126154,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x537165740a9098a1:0xba10eb85a455ac6d!8m2!3d51.083958!4d-114.0589974) is the setup that most of them have.

```
        search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchboxinput"]')
        search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="searchbox-searchbutton"]')
        # now I will fill and clear it after each search
        for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
            val = df.loc[i, "Acceptable"]
            search_box.clear()

            #try:
                #search_box.clear()
            search_box.send_keys(f"{val}")
            search_button.click()
            time.sleep(9)
            save_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/button')
            #save_button = driver.find_element_by_name("Save")
            
            save_button.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            #except:
            #    save_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/button')
            #    save_button.click()
            #    time.sleep(1)
                
            fav_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="action-menu"]/ul/li[2]').click()
            time.sleep(1)
            print(f"Saved {val}")
```

This is the relevant chunk of code, I originally had it in a try and except but that was just cycling through the broken values after hitting the unexpected number of buttons. My thought was to just find the save buttons element id and use that but I literally can't find it when looking in Inspect Element.

I've also tried using `find_element_by_link_text` and `find_element_by_partial_link_text` using `Save` for them and neither worked.

Comment: Google maps uses a lot of iframes. Make sure your navigating them properly with `driver.switch_to.frame` and `driver.switch_to.default_content`

Comment: @SimonNasser Would that be an issue though if it was working for previous companies in the scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
save_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pane"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/button')
```

use this:

```
save_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-value='Save']")
```

Comment: BTW I couldn't find element matching this locator `//*[@id="action-menu"]/ul/li[2]`

Comment: This worked! Why did it give you a different xpath than it gave me? I just right clicked and hit copy xpath. Also, that element you can't find comes up after you click the save button. Maps pulls up a drop down menu and you have to choose from that list to actually save something, kinda lame but whatever.

Comment: You have to learn how to create correct selectors. XPaths and CSS selectors automatically generated by dev tools  etc are bad in 99% cases.

Comment: Well damn, how would one find a better way of getting them then?

Comment: Google `selenium locators best practices` or similar. there are a lot of tutorials!